# SPM Kingfisher SwiftUI Compiler error while archiving

Tags: xcode, swiftui, swift-package-manager, kingfisher

If I try to archive my project, I get many compiler errors with Kingfisher for SwiftUI.
I can run code on my device and on the simulator without any problems.

Xcode Version 13.0 (13A233)
SPM
KingFisher 6.3.1

Have anyone got an idea?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yN2Yw.jpg)

Comment: You need Kingfisher 7.x for Xcode 13 (and don't forget to Clean Build after the update and before rebuilding).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: KingFisher 7.x for Xcode 13 solved this issue. Thank you Eric Aya :-)

Comment: @EricAya could you please turn your comment into answer so Berkant can mark it as correct, and me can upvote? ;)

Comment: @Cemen Ok. I will also add the reference from their site.

Answer (score 1):

**You need Kingfisher 7.x for Xcode 13.**

*It's also good practice to clean the build folder after the package update, before rebuilding.*

Kingfisher's [GitHub page](https://github.com/onevcat/Kingfisher#requirements) has additional explanations:

> If you need to support from iOS 10 (UIKit/AppKit) or iOS 13 (SwiftUI),
> use Kingfisher version 6.x. But it won't work with Xcode 13.
>
> If you need to use Xcode 13 but cannot upgrade to v7, use the
> version6-xcode13 branch. However, you have to drop iOS 10 support due
> to an Xcode 13 bug.

[image: Kingfisher requirements]